# When are @export values set?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I just implemented camera controls into my game. This script contains several @export`ed values and some bunch of derived values too. I tried both cases: with and without @onready modifier and saw that the absence of @onready modifier is not affecting my game, but for the sake of not pushing my luck again, I placed it still. Is @onready required here? How were values calculated correctly without @onready modifier (maybe variables in the body of the class are calculating lazily, or editor overrides are inlined through these decorators`@` into the scripts)?

```
@tool
extends Node3D

@export_group("Step per tap")
@export var rotation_step: float = 5
@export var scaling_step := 0.95

@export_group("Rotation clamps")
@export var max_rotation := 90
@export var min_rotation := 0

@export_group("Gestures scaling")
@export var pan_gesture_rotation_scaling: float = 1
@export var pan_gesture_scale_scaling: float = 1

@onready var _scaling_in_step := scaling_step
@onready var _scaling_out_step := 1 / scaling_step

@onready var _steps_to_max := (rotation_degrees.x - min_rotation) / rotation_step
@onready var _steps_to_min := (rotation_degrees.x - max_rotation) / rotation_step

@onready var _max_scale := scale * _scaling_out_step ** _steps_to_max
@onready var _min_scale := scale * _scaling_in_step ** _steps_to_min


func _input(event: InputEvent):
    pass # camera rotation and scaling handling which uses much of clampf with max* and min* values
```

Comment: To put it simply, even though your script may function without the `@onready` keyword, it's considered a good practice to use it. This helps ensure that variables dependent on the node's status or other nodes in the scene initialize reliably and predictably.

Comment: @AztecCodes I don't consider it a good practice to use `@onready` when it is not necessary, I rather the code be honest, consider it self-documentation. I suspect such advice comes from lack knowledge of how it works, and so I'd consider following said advice to be [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). The Node will always initialize reliable and predictably regardless. However, as initialization becomes complex, consider using `_init` or `_ready` or both, which might be more evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties and script variables without `@onready` are initialized early. The variables are initialized in the order they appear in the script.

The `@onready` variables are set on the ready, which is when the node enters the scene tree for the first time (or after `request_ready` was called) but after the ready of the children. They are also initialized in the order they appear in the script.

*The initialization might trigger the execution of setters. For example, if you add a setter to a variable that does not have `@onready` but has `@export`, its setter might run before the `Node` is inside the scene tree.*

---

So, if the initialization depends on another `Node` (barring `Node` export variables), you NEED to use use `@onready` or do it in `_ready`, as it ensures the `Node` is inside the scene tree, and thus can get other `Node`s.

Trying to get access the scene tree to get another `Node` from the initializer of a variable without `@onready` will result in an ERROR. Because, as mentioned before, those initializers run early, before the `Node` is in the scene tree.

Of course, you also need `@onready` if the initializer of a variable depends on another variable and that other variable has `@onready`.

---

> Is @onready required here? How were values calculated correctly without @onready modifier (maybe variables in the body of the class are calculating lazily, or editor overrides are inlined through these decorators@ into the scripts)?

*I have gone into more detail on the execution order [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/194937/10408).*

Long story short, your code does not benefit from `@onready` at all. That is because the initializers don't need to reach other `Node`s via the scene tree.

---

Instead I would worry about something else: You can change the exported values from the inspector, and the variables that are computed from them won't update.

For that I have described a pattern a few times, but here it goes again:

```
@export var property:String:
    set(mod_value):
        if property == mod_value:
             return

        property = mod_value
        if is_node_ready():
             _update()


func _ready() -> void:
    _update()


func _exit_tree() -> void:
    request_ready()


func _update() -> void:
    # compute here
    pass
```

If the `Node` is in the scene tree and ready has executed already: Any change to the property will call `_update`.

If the `Node` is not in the scene tree or ready has not executed yet: Then `_update` will be called from `_ready`... Which will run the `Node` enters the scene tree (either because it is the first time, or because we called `request_ready` when it exited the scene tree).

*You can use one single `_update` method for all the properties, or multiple. Instead of organizing them by the property they trigger, I find that it makes more sense to organize them by what do they update (as multiple properties might imply to update the same thing)… Which sometimes means calling multiple methods from the setter.*

---

However, I see your code also depends on `scale` which is not immediately obvious how to detect changes of. For that you could use [`set_notify_local_transform`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node3d.html#class-node3d-method-set-notify-local-transform) or [`set_notify_transform`.](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node3d.html#class-node3d-method-set-notify-transform).

Comment: Your answer gave me understanding that these private derived values should no longer be calculated, but set via @ export for clarity and more control. Which in consequence eliminates the whole @ onready question. But on the way here, thanks to you, I found knowledge of Node lifecycle – thank you again.